# Building a "frequency by color" grid from a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have a 4 by 4 matrix, for instance

```
A= matrix(c(4 , 7 , 12 , 2 ,
5 , 5 , 9 , 12 ,
14 , 15 , 6 , 22 ,
0 , 2 , 6 , 4),
nrow=4, 
ncol=4, 
byrow=TRUE)

In[10]:
A

Out[10]:
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    7   12    2
[2,]    5    5    9   12
[3,]   14   15    6   22
[4,]    0    2    6    4
```

I want to consider each of the values in this matrix as a *frequency* and correspondingly create a grid like (*except with colors added to the squares and potentially also the values*)

[(grid picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUhga.gif)

where each square is a color corresponding to a frequency, i.e. I could have have different colors for `0 < x < 4`, `4 <= x <= 9`, etc. etc. where `x` represents each value in my matrix. Basically what is happening is a function is mapping different values into each position in my matrix, and I need a way of visually depicting the frequency with which each square is chosen. This seems like the most intuitive way to do so, but I'm not sure if there is an R library or package that makes something like this very feasible.

Comment: Does `image` not work? the gif you have has no colors, is that on purpose.

Comment: I didn't add colors to the grid, no, I just imagine a grid like that with colors indicating frequencies in each square over some range.

Comment: I would try `image` or if using ggplot then geom_raster. Another trick I've used in the past is to use pch = 15 to plot a square. Is the output of these along the lines of what you want?

Comment: I've used `ggplot` for other purposes, but never `image` nor `geom_raster`, and documentation isn't really getting me anywhere right now. Could you describe a little bit more what exactly you mean?